# How to pass attributes between different portlets on different pages in Liferay

Tags: angularjs, liferay, liferay-6, portlet

lets assume that i have Liferay with 2 pages. Each page contains one different portlet. Both portlets have Angular in their web if that will be helpful somehow. This is because portlets  Now on first page i need to input some data to portlet, then i need to redirect to second page and pass this data to portlet residing there.

This is of course simplified situation because in reality there will be many portlets on first page and many in second. Each portlet on 1 page will add some portions of data which will be consumed by portlets on 2 page.

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you using liferay navigation or angular routes ?? If liferay navigation ,then this is liferay question and you need to use IPC

Comment: I'm considering more of Angularish usage because I'm trying to avoid portlets action. Basically the concept is that portlets only serve as Angular carriers. All logic is going through REST Service App called from Angular. 
Angular will gather some inputs (from REST and user) then redirect to other liferay page with different portlets which needs that data. But i dont know if Liferay can pass some data to web page directly or to portlets on page passing data from POST method.

Comment: You can append data as `queryString` while redirection to the second page and extract there from `request` object.

Comment: Yes I am considering queryString but as "last resource". It's because I'm afraid of to much data needed to be passed and also "business client" may disapprove idea of long URL's. That's why I'm searching for some alternatives. If there will be none better solution i will consider this as an answer. :)